# TypeScript not merging namespaces from multiple files

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've imported types with `typings` and need to extend some of them with additional method definitions. For example, I have this file for `Mocha`:

```
// /typings/globals/mocha/index.d.ts

declare namespace Mocha {

    interface IRunnable {
        title: string;
        fn: Function;
        async: boolean;
        sync: boolean;
        timedOut: boolean;
    }

    interface ITest extends IRunnable {
        parent: ISuite;
        pending: boolean;
        state: 'failed'|'passed'|undefined;

        fullTitle(): string;
    }
}
```

I need to add a method to `IRunnable` and an overload to `ITestDefinition`. In this case the typing is wrong--the method exists but is not in the type declaration. So I tried adding a separate file

```
// /typings/global/custom-additions/index.d.ts

declare namespace Mocha {

    interface IRunnable {
        timeout(value:boolean):void;
    }

    interface ITestDefinition {
        (expectation: string, callback?: () => void): Mocha.ITest;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error in custom-additions itself:

> custom-additions/index.d.ts(420,65): error TS2694: Namespace '".../custom-additions/index".Mocha' has no exported member 'ITest'.

And also an error when trying to reference the added `timeout()` method:

> tests/runner.ts(65,31): error TS2339: Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'ITest'.

At the top of `custom-additions` I've tried adding each of the following:

```
    /// <reference types="Mocha" />

    import 'mocha';

    import * as Mocha from 'mocha';
```

With no resolution to the first error.

Within the calling code I've tried importing Mocha both via

```
    import Mocha = require('mocha');
```

and

```
    import * as Mocha from 'mocha';
```

I've also added

```
    import 'custom-additions';
```

With no success.

I'd appreciate pointers on what I'm doing wrong in trying to merge these namespaces. This is just one example--I have almost identical issues with a dozen or so other type definitions. Most of the custom additions involve actual customizations, others are type fixes as above.